# Printers compatible with case sensitive hardened Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, security, printing

For security improvment, I'm running all my MacOS X on case sensitive
and journaled file systems (then any ill written program which one day open a file named **conf**, and the day after try to open it with the new name **CONF**, won't mess with any of their or my files).

I'd like to buy a new multi-purpose printer
which would be compatible with such an hardened MacOS X.

If you are using a Mountain Lion on a case sensitive and journaled file-system,
could you share here which printer make and model you experienced running without any misbehaviour?

Comment: Do you have a reference that explains the security benefits of a case sensitive file system?  Using a case sensitive file system does allow for software originally written for some other platforms (where the default is case sensitive, eg UNIX) to run without modification.  But the Mac has had a case insensitive file system since 1984 (I believe), so many (otherwise well-written) applications assume this is the case.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2096/_index.html, where Apple say "_Unfortunately, many applications do not work correctly on case-sensitive volumes_".

Comment: → Ashley: the reference is my personnal experience ☺. I'm a security bugs hunter. When an application is confusing `conf` with `CONF` for a file name, this is the signature of bad coding practices and at least of a lack of quality control. These applications have a higher probability to contain other errors on opening and closing files and veryfying syntax of arguments read or written. Hence these applications are leader targets for cybercriminals.

This is a huge progress from Apple to have switched to a case sensitive file system.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  So I'd say you have chosen case sensitivity to assist you with finding security bugs, not to improve your security.  Sorry I can't help with the printer issue.

Answer (score 1):

Epson Expression Premium XP-605 is installed and running correctly on
Lion (10.7.4) on top of a case sensitive filesystem.
The driver version I used is the 9.0.5 from the [Epson web server](http://www.epson.com).

This means that this software went through a **quality control** able to detect programming errors where the same file may be named differently
in different places of the source programs.